# Load frame on button click

Tags: c#, xaml, frame

I am trying to load a Frame on a click of a specific button.
I have to recreate an App (from Delphi to C#). This means, I cannot change anything (Anything Layout related).
I have a couple of buttons, with icons on top, with a second Grid right under the buttons.

[image: Icons and Grid Layout]

When I start the App, it instantly Loads up the Frame (I am not allowed, to show the frame)
Here is my code, to load the frame:

```
 <Grid Margin="0,58,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Frame Name="Page1" Source="/View/_Test/Page1.xaml"/>
 </Grid>
```

This works, as it should. Next step for me, is to load the frame (and close it by a different button) on click of one of the buttons, shown in the Picture above.
Buttons code:

```
 <Button Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="217,21,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Pictures\bmp00001.bmp" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
```

How do I load and close a frame on click of a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your button click event handler, create the new frame and set it as a child of the grid:

```
private void OpenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame f = new Frame();
    f.Source = new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com");
    YourGrid.Children.Add(f);
}
```

And on the other button click handler remove it:

```
private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Find the element with for example linked extension method
    YourGrid.Children.Remove(child);
}
```

One nice way to find an element is in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1759923/3279876